# No icons after update on 29/10

Tags: 14.04, updates, graphics

Yesterday, I had some updates that Ubuntu(14.04) suggested to install, and I didn't pay attention which programs where updated.
After the update the system needed to restart, but I just clicked `Restart Later`.
Now, when the pc starts, the screen has lower resolution than it had yesterday and after logging in, the left side bar doesn't appear on the screen.

I remember having problems updating the Nvidia drivers on previous system updates, but I didn't care much because the system was working, and those errors were shown after the update and not after system reboot.
My graphics card is a Nvidia GT540M.

--- EDIT: ---

I cannot open any graphical terminal (I think) after logging in (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` doesn't do anything), nor do anything else. I get stacked with only the background image. I can only open a tty terminal, but then I cannot run graphcal commands like:

```
unity --reset
```

I think that the problem might come from nvidia so I wanted to uninstall it. If I run:

```
$modprobe -R nvidia
```

I get the nvidia-340 package-driver, but if I try to uninstall it, I get:

```
$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-340
Unable to locate package nvidia-340
```

--- EDIT 2: ---

Thank you for your help. I managed to uninstall the Nvidia drivers and my systems worked. But when I re-install any driver from the Nvidia my system goes to the same situation after rebooting. Neither solution helped in my situation.

(Sadly I do not have enough point to vote up the answers, that were helpful nevertheless).

Answer (score 0):

About resolution first of all check if you use correct driver for you graphics card if yes, try this in terminal :

```
xrandr -s 1024x768( change to your resolution)
```

About bar if it is unity try this in terminal :

```
unity --reset
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity

unity --reset-icons
```

It resets Unity .

Comment: My problem is that I cannot open a terminal (nor open anything else, I think) after logging in. I tried `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` but nothing opens. If I go to tty (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`) then I cannot do anything that involves windows and display (e.g. use the xrandr command you wrote).

Comment: Maybe could you try to create launcher on desktop by right click mouse , then fill "gnome-terminal" as the command and name. then click OK.
 And try to launch it.

Comment: Right click has no effect. The only thing I can do is press either `Cancel` or `Report problem` in the five dialog boxes that are shown when I log into the system.

Comment: did you try  ctrl+alt+f6 combination to login to other user?

Comment: or you could try ctrl+alt+f1 , use your credentials, and then "sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*" after removing drivers , instal them again by writing few commands: 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, and I think it was some kind of update yesterday (I think this is really strange).

So, after booting ubuntu, I went to tty (Ctrl + Alt + F1), and I installed the last nvidia driver I get (write "sudo apt-get install nvidia-" and then hit tab to see the versions available):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates
```

I went back to screen using Ctrl + Alt + F7 (in my case it was F7), and reset computer. Until now is working fine.